# Pandas how to Factorize in Unusual Text Order

Tags: python, pandas, categorical-data, one-hot-encoding

I have a dataframe that has a column 'cat100' that has values like the following:

'A' 'B' ... 'Y' 'Z' 'AA' 'AB' ...

I would like to factorize the column using pd.factorize such that AA is after 'B' 'C' ... 'Z'.

I've tried something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['A','B','AA'])
df[0] = pd.factorize(df[0], sort=True)[0]
```

But this assigns A to 0, B to 2, and AA to 1. I want AA to be assigned to 2 and B to 1.

I've searched for ways to do this and haven't found anything. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: i think you want: `df[0] = df[0].astype('category')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a `DF` with a string column as shown:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(col=['A','B','AA','C','BB','AAA','BC','AB','AA']))
df
```

[image]

***Custom Function:***

(i) Take unique entries from the column under consideration.
(ii) `Groupby` by string lengths and sort these lexicographically and stack them horizontally.
(iii) Factorize them.

```
def complex_factorize(df, col):
    ser = pd.Series(df[col].unique())
    func = lambda x: sorted(x.values.ravel())
    arr = np.hstack(ser.groupby(ser.str.len()).apply(func).values)
    return pd.factorize(arr)
```

Taking the labels and the unique elements of the series returned by the `factorize` method, feed it to [`DF.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) to construct the mapping.

```
val, ser = complex_factorize(df, 'col')
df.replace(ser, val)
```

[image]